# Cron to detect low available memory

Tags: cron

Hello I have a memory leak on my server which I finding it difficult to trace, apparently so is support.  They told me I to try and write a cron to detect when my server is low on memory but I have no idea how to do this.

I use PHP to build my apps on a VPS server with CentOS6 installed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from https://cookbook.wdt.io/memory.html:

> **free** is a standard unix command that displays used and available memory. Used with the options -m it will output the values in megabytes. The last value in the line labeled "-/+ buffers/cache:" shows the total available memory. So we can use grep and awk to get this value and turn it into a number.
>
> `free -m | grep cache: | awk '{ print int($NF) }'`
>
> */5 * * * * ((`free -m | grep cache: | awk '{ print int($NF) }'` >= 50)) && curl -sm 30 http://any_monitoring_url

The "curl ... any_monitoring_url" in the above example is pinging an external monitoring system like [the one we built (wdt.io)](https://wdt.io/) to catch memory leaks and then email / sms / slack you.  This step is not strictly necessary. You could do something as simple as  `touch file_to_check_timestamp` or  `echo "Low Memory!" >> file_to_check_for_low_memory_alerts`.  The problem is that if memory (or CPU or disk space) get pinned, you could hit [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) and the scheduled cron task may not run.  Hence the value of a third-party monitor.

Also see our articles on cron monitoring [CPU](https://cookbook.wdt.io/cpu.html) and [Disk Space](https://cookbook.wdt.io/disk_space.html) and [other recipes](https://cookbook.wdt.io/), in case they're of value as well.